# SvelteKit - Cannot stringify POJOs with symbolic keys with Prisma computed fields

Tags: prisma, sveltekit

My `+page.server.ts` throws following error, coming from the [devalue](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/devalue) package that sveleKit uses to serialize the data:

```
Error: Data returned from `load` while rendering /[clientId]/companies/[companyId] is not serializable: Cannot stringify POJOs with symbolic keys
```

That's because in the `PrismaClient` I use a [computed field](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/computed-fields):

```
const prismaClient = new PrismaClient().$extends({
  result: {
    user: {
      shortFullName: {
        needs: { firstName: true, lastName: true },
        compute(user) {
          return `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When a `prisma` query runs in my `+page.server.ts`. The computed field is a symbol key, because the computed field are only added at runtime?

```json
assignedToUser: {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  [Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

So the question is, how can I solve this error? In SvelteKit or in Prisma?

Many thanks!

Comment: How about removing all function-valued keys or evaluating them, storing the result? (If that is a fully defining characteristic.)

Answer (score 0):

I used [superjson](https://github.com/blitz-js/superjson) to `stringify()` and `parse()` the object. This evaluates the symbol (I guess?).

```
obj = superjson.parse(superjson.stringify(obj));
```

Anyway, this solved the error.